# SQL Server Convert ISO 8601 not working as documented

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) **convert** should properly parse ISO 8601 dates with timezone using 127 as the style parameter.

> The optional time zone indicator, Z, is used to make it easier to map XML datetime values that have time zone information to SQL Server datetime values that have no time zone. Z is the indicator for time zone UTC-0. Other time zones are indicated with HH:MM offset in the + or - direction. For example: 2006-12-12T23:45:12-08:00.

All of the following are valid ISO 8601 dates but return *Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string*.

```
select convert(datetime, N'2014-02-07T13:51:00+07:00', 127)
select convert(datetime, N'2014-02-07T13:51:00+07', 127)
select convert(datetime, N'2006-12-12T23:45:12-08:00', 127)
```

Anyone have a solution or workaround for this issue?

Comment: It looks like you are specifying the style that requires a `Z` *instead of* a time zone. Obviously that doesn't match your input strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Workaround?: Use [`datetimeoffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
select convert(datetimeoffset, N'2014-02-07T13:51:00+07:00', 127) --<-- This one works...
select convert(datetimeoffset, N'2014-02-07T13:51:00+07', 127)
select convert(datetimeoffset, N'2006-12-12T23:45:12-08:00') --<-- and this one works...
```

Comment: Thanks for super quick and accurate answer!

Comment: Relevant for SQL Server 2008 and above.

Answer (score 2):

use `datetimeoffset or datetime2` instead of `datetime`

Comment: Yeah, you tell 'em. That'll teach him to answer eight minutes late.