# Save datetime in sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, datetime-format, sqldatetime

How I can insert with a query a date like this? `2015-06-02T11:18:25.000`

I have tried this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (FIELD) VALUES (convert(datetime,'2015-06-02T11:18:25.000'))
```

But I have returned:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I tried also:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-06-02T11:18:25.000', 126)
```

but it is not working:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

The entire query is:

```
INSERT INTO BOLLE_TEST_POPPER (QIDDIADE,QNUMBOLLA,QSELEZIONALE,QDATA,QORA,QPRIMAPESATA,QSECONDAPESATA,QIMP1,QIMP2,QIDCAUSALE,QIDCLIENTE,QIDDESTINAZIONE,QIDVETTORE,QIDSUBVETTORE,QIDCAMION,QORATRASITO,QNUMBOLLAINGRESSO,QDATABOLLAINGRESSO,QCOMMITTENTIDELTRASPORTO,QANNOTAZIONI,QANNOTAZIONIINBOLLA,QIDARTICOLO,QQANTITA,QIDAUTISTA,QNUMTESSERA,QNUMGETTONE,VALORETAB1,VALORETAB2,VALORETAB3,VALORETAB4,VALORETAB5,VALORETAB6,VALORETAB7,VALORETAB8,VALORETAB9,VALORETAB10,VALORETESTO1,VALORETESTO2,VALORETESTO3,VALORETESTO4,VALORETESTO5,VALORETESTO6,VALORETESTO7,VALORETESTO8,VALORETESTO9,VALORETESTO10) VALUES ('4','5234','-',
convert(datetime,'2015-06-02'),convert(datetime,'2015-06-02T11:18:25.000',126),'30020','20230','null','null','4','1','391','50','50','50','500',convert(datetime,'2015-06-02T11:14:06+02:00',126),'-','false','-','-','19','9790.00','1','BK994P','-','-','null','null','null','null','null','null','null','null','null','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-');
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What is the data type of the table column?  What version of SQL Server.  No convert function should be necessary.

Comment: You're probably focussing on the wrong column in your INSERT. I'd be highly suspicious of those columns where you're attempting to insert the string `'null'` rather than the non-value `null` (note, no quotes). What are the data types of those columns? (Of course, it would be easier if you had posted the whole table definition)

Comment: Also, as a general data modelling tip - if you find yourself creating identical columns except for a numeric suffix, that's usually an indication that this data ought to be split out into a separate table and use separate rows rather than columns to store the values (this helps because you'll sometimes want to query against all such data, which is easier if its all in a single column. Also, you don't have to limit yourself to 10 values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (FIELD) VALUES CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-06-02T11:18:25.000', 126)
```

126 relates to ISO8601, which is the format `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm`.

This is the same format as the string `'2015-06-02T11:18:25.000'`.

For more information, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

For dates with a datetimeoffset (for example `'2015-06-02T11:14:06+02:00'` - note the `+02:00` at the end), you will have to do this:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,'2015-06-02T11:14:06+02:00'), 127)
```

The fully fixed query should be:

```
INSERT INTO BOLLE_TEST_POPPER (QIDDIADE,QNUMBOLLA,QSELEZIONALE,QDATA,QORA,QPRIMAPESATA,QSECONDAPESATA,QIMP1,QIMP2,QIDCAUSALE,QIDCLIENTE,QIDDESTINAZIONE,QIDVETTORE,QIDSUBVETTORE,QIDCAMION,QORATRASITO,QNUMBOLLAINGRESSO,QDATABOLLAINGRESSO,QCOMMITTENTIDELTRASPORTO,QANNOTAZIONI,QANNOTAZIONIINBOLLA,QIDARTICOLO,QQANTITA,QIDAUTISTA,QNUMTESSERA,QNUMGETTONE,VALORETAB1,VALORETAB2,VALORETAB3,VALORETAB4,VALORETAB5,VALORETAB6,VALORETAB7,VALORETAB8,VALORETAB9,VALORETAB10,VALORETESTO1,VALORETESTO2,VALORETESTO3,VALORETESTO4,VALORETESTO5,VALORETESTO6,VALORETESTO7,VALORETESTO8,VALORETESTO9,VALORETESTO10) VALUES ('4','5234','-',
convert(datetime,'2015-06-02'),convert(datetime,'2015-06-02T11:18:25.000',126),'30020','20230','null','null','4','1','391','50','50','50','500',CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,'2015-06-02T11:14:06+02:00'), 127),'-','false','-','-','19','9790.00','1','BK994P','-','-','null','null','null','null','null','null','null','null','null','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-');
```

Comment: That one works, I think you are getting the issue with the other date in your query. If I run the query SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-06-02T11:18:25.000', 126) - it returns a date.

Comment: This one does not work: select convert(datetime,'2015-06-02T11:14:06+02:00',126)

Comment: You will have to convert it like this: CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,'2015-06-02T11:14:06+02:00'), 127)

Comment: Donal's last comment almost works, but you have to drop the '127'. Just: CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,'2015-06-02T11:14:06+02:00')). Alternatively you could skip all the conversions, and just insert LEFT('2015-06-02T11:14:06+02:00', 19)

Comment: I have noticed different behaviours with different versions of Sql Server. It seems to work with 127 in Sql Server 2008 R2 but not in Sql Server 2014.

Answer (score 1):

You need a format.  In this case, 126:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (FIELD)
    VALUES (convert(datetime,'2015-06-02T11:18:25.000', 126))
```

The list is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

For time zones, you need 127, so you need to fix your `values` clause:

```
('4','5234','-',
    convert(datetime,'2015-06-02'),convert(datetime,'2015-06-02T11:18:25.000',127),'30020','20230','null','null','4','1','391','50','50','50','500',convert(datetime,'2015-06-02T11:14:06+02:00',127),'-','false','-','-','19','9790.00','1','BK994P','-','-','null','null','null','null','null','null','null','null','null','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-');
```

Comment: For time zones, you need 127, not 126.

Comment: This will give a conversion failure: select convert(datetime,'2015-06-02T11:14:06+02:00',127), try it.

Comment: @Donal . . . How amusing.  The example given in the *documentation* also fails (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/80).

Comment: @GordonLinoff I was confused about the Z bit in the docs - with time zone Z. Not sure what is meant to go there, the docs were a bit light on that. If you convert the string to a datetimeoffset, you can then convert it to a datetime.

Comment: @donal . . . Look at footnote 7.  I think the explanation is pretty clear there.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, you are correct - I see that now, it should work with 127.

Comment: The issue is marked as closed on Microsoft Connect (I wonder if it is back?): https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/272802/convert-style-127-is-not-working-for-time-zones-indicators-other-than-z-utc-0

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621650/sql-server-convert-iso-8601-not-working-as-documented

Comment: It looks like you need to convert to datetime2 first, and then to datetime http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/89

Comment: @cha no, I think you need to convert to datetimeoffset first - to take the time zone into account. Then convert to datetime. If you look at the return value in the fiddle it is 8 hours out.

Answer (score 1):

just try this. it worked for me.

```
  if(isset($_POST['buttonsave']))
    {
        $vfidperiodo      = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_POST['idperiodo']);
        $vfperiodo        =  ms_escape_string($_POST['periodo']);
        $vffechainicio    =  $_POST['fecha_inicio'];



        $query_in="INSERT INTO iperiodos (idperiodo, periodo, fecha_inicio)
            VALUES ('".$vfidperiodo."','".$vfperiodo."','".$vffechainicio."')";


        $sql_in = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query_in);
       if ($sql_in) // Se eejectuto la sentencia SQL?
                  {
          echo "SQLSuccess"; // Mensaje Afirmativo.
                  } else {
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); // Causa del error.       
                  }
         exit();
    }
```

here's the DB and the Form images.

[image]
[image]